# stylish wise, is it better to have an else after a conditional that throws an exception?

Tags: java, exception, styles

```
public void printLevel(int n){
    if(n<1){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    printLevel(overallRoot, n);
}
```

This is my code. In the industry, would it be better to have an else surrounding the printLevel, acknowledging if the if statement evaluates to false, this is what is going to happen or does it really not matter.?

Comment: There's no hard and fast rule, and differing opinions on what looks nicer (which makes this opinion-based and thus off-topic for SO). Personally, I prefer this fail-fast approach probably 95% of the time; other people prefer an if-else, especially if the method returns something (e.g. if the first bit was `if (n<1) { return SOME_DEFAULT; }`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you throw an exception, you break out of the normal execution flow of the method. Therefore I believe the code following the condition shouldn't be in an `else` clause.

Answer (score 1):

There's no set "rule" you have to follow, since both ways would accomplish the same thing.

That being said, I like to include the `else` simply for readability and clarity.